# Why doesn't my getIndex method work?

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

I have written a method named getIndex and it won't return a number when I run the tester.

```
public int getIndex(String s){
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; (i < names.length && index == 1); i++)
    {
        if(names[i].equals(s)) {
            index = i;
        }        
    }
    return index;
}
```

In case it's not clear, I'm trying to make the method return which place in the array the given string is located.

EDIT--
[here's my code on ideone] (http://ideone.com/CM9xID)

Comment: `for (...; (i < names.length && index == 1); ...`...?

Comment: Why do u have && index == 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate the wrong way, if comparing for index == 1 the loop never starts as index is declared with -1. if you would declare your index with 1, the loop would start but then run endlessly if names[1] is not equal to s, so just remove it and youre good.

```
public int getIndex(String s){
    for(int i = 0; (i < names.length; i++)
    {
        if(names[i].equals(s)) { //use equalsIgnoreCase if comparing should be case insensitive
            return i; //found
        }        
    }
    return -1; //not found
}
```

Another version to do your loop is (if you just want the index you can directly use indexOf() as in the last example shown):

```
List<String> names2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
for(String name : names2){
    if(name.equals(s))
        return names2.indexOf(name);
}
```

This is an enhanced for [loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).

You can also shortcut and directly get the index:

```
 List<String> names2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
 return names2.indexOf(s);
```

[Ideone Fiddle](http://ideone.com/rfUtuS)

Be aware that you always only get the index of the first occurence. if s is more than once inside the array you must enhance it to store the indexes found and return all of them!

```
public List<Integer> getIndexes(String s){
    List<Integer> found = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; (i < names.length; i++)
    {
        if(names[i].equals(s)) { //use equalsIgnoreCase if comparing should be case insensitive
            found.add(i);
        }        
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Alright, that seems a bit easier. How would I put this in my method?

public int getIndex(String s){
for(String name : names){
    if(name.equals(s))
        return name.indexOf(s);
}
wouldn't I need another return statement?
}

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is false right away.

You code says:

**while** `0 < LENGTH_OF_NAMES` **AND** `-1 is equal to 1`

-1 is **never equal** to 1 so your loop never happens

Change:

```
for(int i = 0; (i < names.length && index == 1); i++)
```

To:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
```

Comment: @gantners i can never == 1 because it starts at 0 and never gets incremented because the loop can never be entered because index starts at -1 so it is never == 1.

Comment: @nem, I have posted an edit to my code showing my full code on ideone

Comment: @Frightlin Your edit changes nothing about the question you asked.